# Labeling points in plot made from a dataset

Tags: plotting, dataset, labeling

I am trying to use Mathematica to do some data analysis. I am trying to label points in a plot of a dataset. I know that `Callout` should work, but can't for the life of me figure out how to make it when I'm plotting `b` against `a` and then labeling the points with `c`.

Here is a subset of the dataset:

```
dataset = 
  Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 0.0, "b" -> -1.26, "c" -> 1|>,
   <|"a" -> 0.3, "b" -> -1.25, "c" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 0.6, "b" -> -1.26, "c" -> 3|>,
   <|"a" -> 0.9, "b" -> -1.19, "c" -> 4|>,
   <|"a" -> 1.2, "b" -> -0.8, "c" -> 5|>,
   <|"a" -> 1.5, "b" -> -0.98, "c" -> 6|>}]

ListLinePlot[Callout[dataset[All, {1, 2}], dataset[All, 3]]]
```

[image]

This doesn't give me what I want as I want to label each point.

I realize I'm missing something fundamental in terms of associating each point. Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks for the two solutions. I want to modify the plot by assigning the plot to "g" and then using Show:

```
Show[g, ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse", PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

but do not see how to do it. I tried using Show without success.

Comment: Does `dataset[Map[Callout[{#a, #b}, #c] &] /* ListLinePlot]` do what you want?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Hard to get my head around some of Mathematica's cryptic code.

Comment: Alright, I'll post an answer later...

Comment: @J.M.'sennui That could also be written as `dataset[ListLinePlot, Callout[{#a, #b}, #c] &]`.

Comment: @WReach, that's way less awkward; please write an answer so I can upvote it. :)

Comment: For my second part about ScalingFunctions and PlotTheme I modified J. M.'s ennui answer: `ListLinePlot[dataset[Map[Callout[{#a, #b}, #c] &]], 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse", PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239902/labeling-points-in-plot-made-from-a-dataset?noredirect=1#comment605683_239902) by @J.M.~~___, here is one way to do it:

```
dataset[ListLinePlot, Callout[{#a, #b}, #c] &]
```

Additional options can be added to `ListLinePlot` like this:

```
dataset[
  ListLinePlot[#, ScalingFunctions->"Reverse", PlotTheme->"Detailed"]&
, Callout[{#a, #b}, #c] &
]
```

[image: ListLinePlot image]